# I am interested in accessing the uibutton method from external method but I'm getting lot of errors

Tags: ios, swift

Below is my code. I have 9 buttons in my view whose background image is to be changed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let alerts = UIAlertController(title: "Hi", message: "Hello", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (<#UIAlertAction#>) in
        for i in 0..<9
        {
            let newButton = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            newButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: ""), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "cross.png"), for:.normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are adding those 9 buttons?

Comment: What are the errors? What lines are causing them? Please [edit] your question with these details.

Comment: i am trying to access the buttons in the bellow code..                                    let newButton = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
            newButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: ""), for: .normal)

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is the issue you are facing? still not clear about your question

Comment: are you adding buttons in xib or storyboard?

Comment: i need to delete the background image of those buttons

Comment: buttons are already added to the story board. I need to delete their background image

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
newButton .setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: ""), for: .normal)
newButton .setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "cross.png"), for: .selected)

 @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected;
    }
```

Comment: can you help me out  in finding , how to point the new button variable from function other than IB function (which is already created in the story board with specific tag)

Comment: if currentSymbol == 1
            {
                sender .setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "cross.png"), for: UIControlState())
                currentState[sender.tag] = 1
                
                currentSymbol = 2
            }
            else if currentSymbol == 2
            {
                sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "nought.png"), for: UIControlState())
                currentState[sender.tag] = 2
                
                
                currentSymbol = 1
                
            }

Comment: this is the code i am using to change the background image when clicked..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add action to UIAlertController. Add following line after defining action1:

```
[alerts addAction: action1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

first add button to the view and add action for it :

```
for i in 0..<9
    {
            let newButton = UIButton(frame : yourFrame)
            newButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: ""), for: .normal)
            newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            newbutton.tag = i
            self.view.addSubview(newButton:)
    }
```